# PUT request with JSON payload sent from Postman, nested object not parsed

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, postman

I didn't have this problem before, with other POJOs, I'm not sure what's different this time, but I can't get this working and I could not find an exact solution for this.

I have this POJO called Component (with some Hibernate annotations):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="component", uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(
    columnNames = {"name", "component_type"})})
public class Component {

@Column(name="id")
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;

@Column(name="component_type")
private String componentType;

@Column(name="serial_number")
private int serialNumber;

@Column(name="active_since")
private String activeSince;

@Embedded
private ComponentWearoutModel wearout;

public Component() {
}

public Component(String name, String componentType, int serialNumber, String activeSince,
        ComponentWearoutModel wearout) {
    this.name = name;
    this.componentType = componentType;
    this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
    this.activeSince = activeSince;
    this.wearout = wearout;
}

public ComponentWearoutModel getModel() {
    return wearout;
}

public void setModel(ComponentWearoutModel wearout) {
    this.wearout = wearout;
}

//more getters and setters

}
```

ComponentWearoutModel:

```
@Embeddable
public class ComponentWearoutModel {

private String componentType; //dont mind the stupid duplicate attribute
private Integer componentLifeExpectancy;
private Float componentWearOutLevel;
private Float actionThreshold;

public ComponentWearoutModel() {
}

public ComponentWearoutModel(String componentType, int componentLifeExpectancy, float componentWearOutLevel,
        float actionThreshold) {
    this.componentType = componentType;
    this.componentLifeExpectancy = componentLifeExpectancy;
    this.componentWearOutLevel = componentWearOutLevel;
    this.actionThreshold = actionThreshold;
}

//getters and setters
}
```

The sample payload I use:

```
{
"name": "component name",
"componentType": "airfilter2",
"serialNumber": 573224,
"activeSince": "2016-04-10 17:38:41",
"wearout":
    {
        "componentType": "airfilter",
        "componentLifeExpectancy": 1000,
        "componentWearOutLevel": 0.24,
        "actionThreshold": 0.2
    }
 }
```

And finally the resource class:

```
@Path("myresource")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON  + ";charset=UTF-8")
public class MyResource {

DatabaseManager dm = DatabaseManager.getInstance();

@PUT
@Path("Component")
public Response storeComponent(Component component){
    System.out.println("reached");
    System.out.println(component.getComponentType()); //okay
    System.out.println(component.getModel().getComponentType()); //nullpointerexception
    ComponentWearoutModel model = new ComponentWearoutModel("type", 1000,    1f, 0.2f);
    component.setModel(model); //this way it's saved in the db just fine
    dm.save(component);
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(component).build();
}
}
```

Without the prints, only the fields which are not part of the ComponentWearoutModel class are stored in the database table, the other columns are null. So when I try to print one of them, I get an exception, I just dont understand why. If I create a ComponentWearoutModel in the resource method and add it to the component, everything is fine in the database.

**UPDATE**:

so my mistake was that I named the ComponentWearoutModel attribute as "wearout" in the Component.class, but the autogenerated getters and setter were called getModel/setModel and moxy could not parse my payload because of this. Solution: change the attribute name to "model" in Component class and in payload too.

Comment: i cant see any element model it the component class. did you mean wearout?

Comment: what do you mean exactly?

Comment: you are using "component.setModel(model);" - where is the function setModel() ?

Comment: it's one of the setters, which I only indicated with a "//getters and setters" comment that it's there. I wanted to shorten the question.

Comment: so the attribute name is model? or wearout?

Comment: as you can see, in the Component POJO it's wearout, but in the resource class I instantiated with the name "model". I dont see how is this relevant though. (no syntax error on that part)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108803/discussion-between-sampada-and-zoltan-umlauf).

Comment: Make sure component.getModel() is not null. I mean your object 'Model' is null

Comment: How are you getting object by calling getModel() method? Is the object is instantiate?

Comment: Sampada helped me figure it out in chat, that the problem was that the attribute name was wearout in the Component class, but the setter and getter name was setModel/getModel, so moxy had trouble parsing it. Changing the attribute name to model solved it. Damn auto generate by eclipse :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure that the attribute names you are using in the POJO are same as what are being sent in the json string.

Since there are no jackson etc annotations being used in your POJO to tell it the corresponding json mapping, the underlying code will directly use the names given in json string. If you are using the string "model", the convertor code will look for a "setModel" method in your POJO.

In the above example, either call everything "model", or "wearable".